# layout is not clickable outside the scrollview in android

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, clickable

I have a `ScrollView` and I want to be clickable and scrollable.
Relative layout is my root layout.
Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:id="@+id/cardOpt2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:clickable="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnOpt2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove `android:clickable="false"` for scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your scrollView as root layout and set :

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Do this :

```
 <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clickable="false"
          android:fillViewport="true"
          android:clipToPadding="false">

            <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:clickable="true"
               android:clipToPadding="false"
               android:id="@+id/cardOpt2">

               <TextView
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:id="@+id/btnOpt2" />

            <RelativeLayout/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `android:fillViewport="true"` used in `ScrollView` not in `RelativeLayout`

Comment: your wellcome @Bindiyarathod